# MYSQL timestamp coming as null on insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am adding a user selected timestamp to MYSQL table using the query

```
INSERT INTO schedule( pending_id, scheduled_time ) 
VALUES (
"477", TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "09/02/2016 12:33 PM", "%m/%d/%y %h:%i %p")))
```

But the value of field scheduled_time is coming as NULL in DB. What could be the issue?

Comment: What is the type of the `scheduled_time` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL `TIME()` function extracts the time portion of a timestamp.  Hence your `INSERT` query is the same as doing this:

```
INSERT INTO schedule (pending_id, scheduled_time)
VALUES ("477", '12:33:00')
```

In other words, you are not actually inserting a timestamp, but rather just a time string fragment.  This is resulting in a `NULL` value being inserted.

Instead, you should have just stopped after calling `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
INSERT INTO schedule (pending_id, scheduled_time)
VALUES ("477", STR_TO_DATE("09/02/2016 12:33 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p"))
```

which would become

```
INSERT INTO schedule (pending_id, scheduled_time)
VALUES ("477", '2016-09-02 12:33:00')
```

**Update:**

I also changed the format string you were using in `STR_TO_DATE` from

```
%m/%d/%y %h:%i %p
```

to

```
%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p
```

since your input string has the year as 4 digits (`%Y`), rather than two (`%y`).

Answer (score 1):

Try the same query but with uppercase %Y (4 digit year):

```
INSERT INTO schedule( pending_id, scheduled_time ) 
VALUES (
"477", TIME( STR_TO_DATE( "09/02/2016 12:33 PM", "%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p")))
```

Comment: it is inserting as 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: I see, have a look at Tim answer. You are inserting a time into a timestamp so you need to remove TIME() function

Comment: @ipeiro You still deserve credit for finding the `%y` problem.  That was also wrong.

Comment: my scheduled_time  column datatype is timestamp, and this query worked for me

Comment: yah,after removing TIME() method it is working.Thank you